# Laravel Livewire update deep nested Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, nested, laravel-livewire

I have created a Livewire Form which includes couple of deep nested relations. How can I update this relations in livewire on submit?

Here is my trying:

class ProfileForm extends Component
{

```
use WithFileUploads;

public $upload;
/**
 * @var
 */
public User $user;

/**
 * @var
 */
public $specialistations;

/**
 * @var
 */
public $occupationGroups;

/**
 * @var
 */
public $professionGroups;



protected array $rules = [
    'user.account.company' => ['integer', 'nullable'],
    'user.account.specialisations' => ['nullable', 'array'],
    'user.account.professions' => [],
    'user.account.occupations' => ['nullable', 'array'],
    'user.account.about' => ['string', 'nullable'],
    'user.account.company_addon' => ['nullable'],
    'user.account.company_phone' => ['nullable'],
    'user.account.company_email' => ['email', 'nullable'],
    'user.account.phone' => ['nullable'],
    'user.account.published' => ['nullable'],
    'user.account.web' => ['nullable'],
    'user.account.company_fax' => ['nullable'],
    'user.account.fax' => ['nullable'],
    'user.account.email' => ['email'],
    'upload.*' => 'image|max:1024',
];


/**
 * @return void
 */
public function mount()
{
    $user = auth()->user()->load(['account', 'account.specialisations']);
    $this->specialistations = Specialisation::get();
    $this->occupationGroups = OccupationGroup::get();
    $this->professionGroups = Profession::get();
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function submit()
{
    if($this->upload) {
        $this->user->avatar = $this->upload->store('files', 'public');
    }

    $this->user->update();
    $this->user->account->update();
}


public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.profile-form');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Livewire docs - nested data](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#binding-nested-data), you can save the related model

```php
public function submit()
{
    if($this->upload) {
        $this->user->avatar = $this->upload->store('files', 'public');
    }

    $this->validate();

    $this->user->save();
    $this->user->account->save();
}
```

###### Update: (For anyone visiting in future)

> the problem is that $this->user->account is having other relations and the save will fail with SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'professions' in 'field list'

As pointed out by OP- @fefe himself, ensure that all the relations are loaded (all relations which are used, updated in the component).

In the `mount()` method

```php
public function mount()
{
    $user = auth()->user()->load([
        'account', 
        'account.specialisations',
        'account.professions',
        'account.occupations',
    ]);

    $this->specialistations = Specialisation::get();
    $this->occupationGroups = OccupationGroup::get();
    $this->professionGroups = Profession::get();
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

###### Option Two (Better)

Split the component into two: one for user and another component for user account.

Then handle saving all the relations of account in `UserAccount` component. If the relations are nested only a single level deep then it should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for Feedback! I tried before but this will fail with `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::update(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/dashboard/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php on line 23 and exactly 1 expected`

Comment: @fefe So as per Livewire docs example you need to use `save()` even for nested data including relationships. Have updated my answer, check if it works for you.

Comment: the problem is that `$this->user->account` is having other relations and the save will fail with `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'professions' in 'field list'`

Comment: thanks for the updates. If i'm going with the better Approach that would mean that I have to separate submit action? Literally I have to wrap those in 2 Forms?

Comment: Having two separate forms on a single page would be better and also more intuitive for the users. If a user wants to just update the account details then it is not required to submit unchanged user model data and vice versa.

Comment: yeah but in my case user could update the avatar which is having relation to the user model

Comment: So you can have one component: `UserForm` with one level deep nested relationship to `avatar` and another component `UserAccount` with multiple one level deep nested relationships - `specialisations`, `professions`, `occupations` and so on. As a side note, if a user can have only one avatar image - then it's better to have a column `avatar` on the user table itself. Similarly if professions & occupations can be array of names & no other details are required to be stored - t would be better to store them as column on `user_accounts` table

Comment: this is somehow buggy, I gave a try with the better approach but still having problems on update/save `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'professions' in 'field list'
update
  `bdb_members`
set
  `about` = Nutzen Sie den Freitext,
  um sich und ihr Profil zu schärfen.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.Lorem ipsum.Maximal 1000 Zeichen,
  `professions` = ?,
  `occupations` = ?,
  `email` = ?,
  `bdb_members`.`updated_at` = 2022 -05 -28 21: 53: 46
where
  `id` = 163` the line `$this->account->save();`

Comment: I think I got the issue: it seems to be a declaration problem on `$user = auth()->user()->load(['account', 'account.specialisations']);` while does not contains all relations

Comment: Great! So then let me delete this answer. What say @fefe ?

Comment: you can leave the answer because the hint on `save` instead of `update` is correct and I will accept

Comment: @fefe Thanks. Have updated the answer to hint at loading all required relationships, for any future visitors. Feel free to edit/update the answer if anything else led to the resolution of the issue.